# Stuck on Turning on Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm trying to turn on Bluetooth programmatically:

```
startActivityForResult( new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE) , 1);

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
}
```

Sometimes it works, but sometimes it gets stuck on "Turning on Bluetooth" screen. When this happens it never reaches `onActivityResult()`.

What could be causing the problem?

I'm using API 10

Answer (score 0):

Use defaultAdapter and then call these function in your Intent calling

```
BluetoothAdapter adapter=BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
//and to enable bluetooth just use
adapter.enable();
//and to disable bluetooth just use
adapter.disable();
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this code might work out,

```
public void enableBT(View view){
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
    Intent intentBtEnabled = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE); 
    // The REQUEST_ENABLE_BT constant passed to startActivityForResult() is a locally defined integer (which must be greater than 0), that the system passes back to you in your onActivityResult()  
    // implementation as the requestCode parameter.  
    int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    startActivityForResult(intentBtEnabled, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    } }
```

Don't forget to add the following permission in your android_manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
```